# Конвертация PDF в JPG на с помощью JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Использую библиотеку [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/) для генерации pdf. Теперь есть потребность конвертировать сгенерированный файл в jpg. Идеальный вариант сделать это на фронтенде. Какие посоветуете решения этого вопроса?

Comment: Используйте, но здесь задавать вопросы необходимо такие, ответы на которые основываются на фактах, а не на мнениях. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вот держите готовый скрипт конвертации PDF в JPG https://gist.github.com/ichord/9808444